# How to Invalidate Magento 2's Specific Cache using CACHE_TAG

Tags: magento2, cache

I want to invalidate particular cache tags when admin saves an attribute. How should I do it.

Answer (score 4):

OK. In that case, use cache invalidator in Controller. I found an example for you. Execute method in Controller class must be:

```
public function execute()
   {
       /** @var Page $resultPage */
       $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

       /* Invalidate Full Page Cache */
       $this->cache->invalidate('YOUR_CUSTOM_CACHE_TYPE_CODE');

       return $resultPage;
   }
```

See more [here](https://www.atwix.com/development/managing-cache-programmatically/).

Answer (score 3):

Create observer

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CacheInvalidator implements ObserverInterface
{
 /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $typeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $typeList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $typeList
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->typeList = $typeList;
    }
}
```

$config will help you check cache enabling. 
Create execute method in CacheInvalidator class  with

```
if ($this->config->isEnabled()) {
            $this->typeList->invalidate(
                \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
            );
        }
```

Comment: No, This is to invalidate full page cache only. I want a code to invalidate my custom cache.

Comment: To change this from invalidating the full page cache, just change the string being passed into the typeList::invalidate method from '\Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER' to 'YOUR_CUSTOM_CACHE_TYPE_CODE'

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a class that implements `\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface`

Then, i.e. if you want to mark a cache as invalid, or even clear it, you can do something like this:

```
$this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
```

or

```
$this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
```